# I am validating my css in http://www.css-validator.org/validator then i getting one Parse Error. How can I solve this?

Tags: css

These is my media query section css codes.

```css
@media (min-width:320px) and (max-width:575px){
    .chakra{
        width: 100%;
        float: unset;
        margin: auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the full error? including the number of line, etc

Comment: That's strange; the validator you mention  looks remarkably like the real W3C validator at http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/, but the real one doesn't report errors.

Comment: In this jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator not showing the error boss.

Comment: OK, so use the real one in the future.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try to add a media as well,

e.g.

```
@media screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:575px){
    .chakra{
        width: 100%;
        float: unset;
        margin: auto;
    }
}
```